# How to remove duplicate who are followed each other in a list

Tags: python, list, duplicates, tuples

In a list I need to delete duplicate that follow each other in a list
like in this example:

```py
[("0", "1"), ("1", "2"), ("0", "2"), ("2", "0")]
```

and the output I want:

```py
["0", "1", "2", "0", "2", "0"]
```

I tried nothing because I have no idea what to do, maybe iterate over the list and use `if index[0] == index[1]`.

Comment: why is the output a list with a single tuple in it?

Answer (score 2):

Use a simple nested loop tracking the previous element:

```
l = [('0', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('0', '2'), ('2', '0')]

out = []
prev = None
for t in l:
    for x in t:
        if x != prev:
            out.append(x)
        prev = x
print(out)
```

Output: `['0', '1', '2', '0', '2', '0']`

If you really want a list with a single tuple:

```
out = [tuple(out)]
```

Output: `[('0', '1', '2', '0', '2', '0')]`

Answer (score 2):

you need to flatten your list first (i do that with [`chain(*lst)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain)) and then you could use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) in order to skip consecutive duplicates:

```
from itertools import chain, groupby

lst = [('0', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('0', '2'), ('2', '0')]
ret = [item for item, _ in groupby(chain(*lst))]

print(ret) # ['0', '1', '2', '0', '2', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in several successive steps (which could actually be merged):

```
tuplist = [('0', '1'), ('1', '2'), ('0', '2'), ('2', '0')]

# unpacking tuples
list2 = []
for t in tuplist:
    list2.extend(t) #shorter way of doing list2 += [t[0], t[1]]
    
# removing duplicates
list3 = [list2[0]]
for i in list2[1:]:
    if i != list3[-1]:
        list3.append(i)
        
# converting list3 to the desired format
list4 = [tuple(list3)]
```

Comment: you could also just `extend` `list2` with `t`

Comment: Indeed, `extend` is one of the methods I forget to use; thanks.